# iOS 12.1.4 not installing In-House enterprise app

Tags: ios, enterprise-distribution

We have enterprise account via we create the build and distribute it via enterprise but in ios 12.1.4 its not installing ...there is no MDM option for trust the certificate

Comment: it works in 12.1.3 I installed an enterprise build yesterday.....is it showing any error message or something?

Comment: yes but in 12.1.4 its not working my app icon is also not visible ...i am in stuck how to install the enterprise app on device

Comment: It was problem in MDM server issue resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was problem in MDM server issue resolved